# Algorithm/Library for merged english words analysis

Tags: algorithm, validation, nlp, grammar

I'm currently having a lot of data (subtitles for films) which contains "compound words" in english.

There is no certain pattern, but in some places words are merged. E.g.:

```
   You got to keep going. They're always looking **forsomething** under the     seats.
```

I don't have specific constraints on language/platform, however there is really lots and lots of data and I won't be able to check results properly. So I need kind of highly-precise solution here.

So what are basically the ways to attack this kind of data?

Comment: Are you trying to detect and correct *incorrectly* merged sequences of English words?  If so, the dynamic programming-based algorithm here will also work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31138025/47984.  This will handle sequences of more than 2 words and is quite fast and flexible.  Note though that there's really no hope of catching accidentally merged word sequences *that happen to also be real English words*, e.g., `a typical` -> `atypical`.

Comment: Just a note on terminology: "compound word" is typically used for words that are used together to convey a meaning (e.g., verbs like "get off", "switch on", or nouns like "New York"), not for whitespace-errors of the kind you are looking to resolve.